# Regex check if a string contains only digits doesn't work

Tags: java, regex

This is my code and I have no idea why it returns false

```
    "A123".matches("\\D+");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are yet another victim among the tens/hundreds of Java devs who are bitten *daily* by the fact that `.matches()` is misnamed.

It will try and match *the whole input*. This is not what you want.

You have to go through a `Pattern`, a `Matcher` and `.find()` instead:

```
private static final Pattern NONDIGIT = Pattern.compile("\\D");

// Test whether there is any nondigit character in a string:
NONDIGIT.matcher(theString).find();
```

You should especially do that since anyway `.matches()` will recompile a `Pattern` each time; here, you have only one `Pattern`.

Answer (score 3):

it must be:

```
"A123".matches("^\\d+$");
```

lowercase `d` stands for a digit `^` for the beginning of the string and `^` for the end of the string.

Comment: No need for anchors; look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
"A123".matches("[0-9]+")
```

Also as you have tagged it as Java then there is an alternate way to use [NumberUtil.isNumber(String str)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html) from Apache which can check this for you.